# How to retrieve the children categories without the children of those ones?

Tags: sql, mysql, tree, hierarchical-data

Here is my statement :

```
SELECT (
  COUNT( parent.categoryName ) - ( sub_tree.depth +1 ) ) AS depth,
  CONCAT( REPEAT( '', ( COUNT( parent.categoryName ) - ( sub_tree.depth +1 ) ) ) , node.categoryName ) AS categoryName

FROM 
  Categories AS node,
  Categories AS parent,
  Categories AS sub_parent,
 (
  SELECT node.categoryName, (
     COUNT( parent.categoryName ) -1) AS depth
     FROM 
       Categories AS node,
       Categories AS parent
     WHERE 
       node.categoryLft BETWEEN parent.categoryLft AND parent.categoryRgt
   AND node.categoryName LIKE 'Product'

     GROUP BY node.categoryName
     ORDER BY node.categoryLft
  ) AS sub_tree
WHERE 
    node.categoryLft BETWEEN parent.categoryLft AND parent.categoryRgt
AND node.categoryLft BETWEEN sub_parent.categoryLft AND sub_parent.categoryRgt
AND sub_parent.categoryName = sub_tree.categoryName

GROUP BY node.categoryName
ORDER BY node.categoryLft
```

It works great, but i would have liked to modify it to get only the first nodes next to the selected category (here 'Products') without the children of the sub categories

Like : 
Products :

- TypeA

  - SubTypeA
  - SubTypeB
- TypeB

I want to get 'TypeA', 'TypeB'.

By the way, here is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE `Categories` (
 `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `categoryLft` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `categoryRgt` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `categoryName` varchar(255) default NULL,
 `categoryAlias` varchar(255) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`categoryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Just a question, is it really needed to create such a complicated categorization mechanism? If its not I can supply you a simple and enough for every task category table and queries.

Comment: It will be used to categorize any types of things, and i don't have any ideas on how the categories will look like, i just have one rules 'a category could have many sub categories'.
It will be used to centralize categories independently of the categorized objects. (It could users, articles, products, etc...)
But i'm still open to any new good ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  child.*
FROM    categories parent
JOIN    categories child
ON      child.categoryLft BETWEEN parent.categoryLft AND parent.categoryRgt
WHERE   parent.id = @id_of_products
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    categories grandchild
        WHERE   grandchild.categoryLft BETWEEN child.categoryLft AND child.categoryRgt
        )
```

`Nested sets` model you are using is *very* hard to manage.

You may want to read this article in my blog:

- [**Hierarchical queries in `MySQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/)

which describes how to implement a much more simple `adjacency list` model in `MySQL`.